# DatabaseContext.Database.SqlQuery<T> error getting nullable columns

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database table which contains an `INT NULL` column called **RuntimeInputID** (other stuff omitted for brevity:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Input](
    [InputID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RuntimeInputID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Input] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InputID] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Input]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Input_RuntimeInput] FOREIGN KEY([RuntimeInputID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Input] ([InputID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Input] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Input_RuntimeInput]
GO
```

My model has the following property defined, and also contains a static method that calls a repository to do work (other properties/methods removed for brevity):

```
[Table("Input")]
public class Input
{
    private static IInput _repo = Factory_Repository.CreateInputRepo();

    [Column("RuntimeInputID")]
    public int? RuntimeInputID { get; set; }

    public static Input[] GetAllInput()
    {
        try
        {
            return _repo.GetAll().ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class Repo_Input : IInput
{
    public IEnumerable<Input> GetAll()
    {
        List<SqlParameter> objSqlparam = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter("@LineID",DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@Mode","SELECT_ALL")
            };

        DataAccessHelper.SetDbNullForNullValues(objSqlparam);

        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            // **Exception thrown here**
            return db.Database.SqlQuery<Input>("usp_Input_Read @LineID, @Mode", objSqlparam.ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

---

When I call `GetAll()`, I get the following exception on the `SqlQuery<Input>` line:

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

All the searching I have done so far talks about either making sure the property is nullable (which mine is), or using a null coalescing operator (which I don't think I need).

How can I get this code to work?

Comment: *"other properties/methods removed for brevity*" Are you sure the problem is not with some other property? Because the exception message is referring to **Decimal** value...

Comment: You're exactly right.  One of the other columns did have a null value in it that I did not expect.  Once I fixed that null value, everything worked.  Good call, thanks!